# WPF ListView items binding to each other

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I have a listview in WPF which holds an observable collection of objects.
The objects are simple rectangular boxes containing a set of radio buttons:

[image: List Object example]

The two sets of radio buttons are kept separate by setting the 'GroupName' in xaml to either `GroupName="Numbers"` or `GroupName="Letters"`

--EDIT--
As requested, here is the code within MyObject for the radiobuttons:

```
<RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" GroupName="Numbers" IsChecked="{Binding IsOne, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" GroupName="Numbers" IsChecked="{Binding IsOne, Converter={StaticResource NegateBoolConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" GroupName="Letters" IsChecked="{Binding IsA, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" GroupName="Letters" IsChecked="{Binding IsA, Converter={StaticResource NegateBoolConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Negate bool converter simply returns the inverse of the bool value.

--End Edit--

The problem comes when I have a list of two of these objects in my list view. The first object (object 1) for example has 'One' and 'A' selected. 
If I then select 'B' in object 2, the selection will try and change for object 1 as well (which messes everything up)
Here is an example of what I am hoping to achieve:

[image: Multiple list objects with different selections]

Has anyone seen this behaviour? On winforms it's fixed by setting a new BindingContext for each item but I don't know whether this is the same in WPF.

I am working in a fully MVVM environment, here is the code for the listview:

```
<ListView Name="ObjectsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <ContentControl>
                   <local:MyObject DataContext="{Binding}"/>
               </ContentControl>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Please can someone let me know how to achieve separate behaviour in my listview items?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How you bind the selected radioubutton ? Could you place more code there? For local:MyObject ?

Comment: I have edited to show the radio button binding. The listview code is complete, this is how it actually appears in the program. (WIth a few margins and alignment statements removed!)

Comment: problem here is the radiobutton and groupname because in each listviewitem it creates a radiobutton with groupname the same, so it only allows to select the one item in that groupname.

Comment: Yes, if I make that groupname dependent on model it works fine, do you want full answer?

Comment: ooh yes please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that each item of listview creates radiobutton which the same GroupName, in wpf it is only possible to select one radiobutton from group. 
So if you got two items ore more the radiobuttons will belong to one common Group.

Solution:
I add two new properties to Model (your class of SelectObject)

```
private string _NameFirst;
public string NameFirst
{
    get { return _NameFirst; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _NameFirst)
        {
             _NameFirst = value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
     }
 }

 private string _NameSecond;
 public string NameSecond
 {
     get { return _NameSecond; }
     set
     {
         if (value != _NameSecond)
         {
            _NameSecond = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
          }
      }
}
```

Each model item of the list should have different NameFirst and NameSecond, there are multiple ways to do so. E.g item1 : (NameFirst="A1",NameSecond="B1"), item2 : (NameFirst="A2", NameSecond="B2".

Also I modify the ContentControl of ListView I modified to StackPanel only for simplicity, you can stay with grid as well.

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="One" Grid.Row="0" GroupName="{Binding NameFirst}" IsChecked="{Binding IsOne, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <RadioButton  Content="Two" GroupName="{Binding NameFirst}" IsChecked="{Binding IsOne, Converter={StaticResource NegateBoolConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <RadioButton Content="A" GroupName="{Binding NameSecond}" IsChecked="{Binding IsA, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <RadioButton  Content="B" GroupName="{Binding NameSecond}" IsChecked="{Binding IsA, Converter={StaticResource NegateBoolConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```